# How to make button in query with style none to style block with session in JSP?

Tags: css, jsp, button, styles

im just beginning coding with JSP. I just get confuse how to make the button in my table query visible only for admin session. here's my code:

```
   <% if(session.getAttribute("user").equals("admin")){
   %><script> $(document).ready(function(){
   document.getElementById("btn_lihat").style.display="block";});</script></code></pre>


    <% //some form submit }
                           %>
```

and here's my table with query...

```
 <table border ="1">
 <tr bgcolor="#7a9ac3">            
                <td>No</td>
                <td>Perihal</td>
                <td>Tanggal</td>
                <td>Jenis</td>
                <td>Tujuan</td>
                <td>Gambar</td>
                <td>Ket</td>
            </tr>
 <% 
 try{
    Koneksi konek = new Koneksi();
    Connection conn = konek.bukaKoneksi();
    Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from surat";
    ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(sql);
           while(res.next()){
               %>
               <tr>
                <td><%=res.getString(1) %></td>
                <td><%=res.getString(2) %></td>
                <td><%=res.getString(3) %></td>
                <td><%=res.getString(4) %></td>
                <td><%=res.getString(5) %></td>
                <td><a href="<%=res.getString(6) %>"><img src="<%=res.getString(6) %>" width="60" height="80"></a></td>
                <td><a href="ServletSurat?nomor=<%=res.getString(1) %>" ><div id="btn_lihat" style="display: none"><input type="submit" name="cmd" value="lihat" id="lihat"></div></a></td>
            </tr>

     <%
           }}
   catch(Exception e){
      out.print(e);
        }
   %>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to check whether its admin, at the time of adding button.
Change

```
<td><a href="ServletSurat?nomor=<%=res.getString(1) %>" ><div id="btn_lihat" style="display: none"><input type="submit" name="cmd" value="lihat" id="lihat"></div></a></td>
```

to

```
<td><a href="ServletSurat?nomor=<%=res.getString(1) %>" >
<% if(session.getAttribute("user").equals("admin")){%>
<div id="btn_lihat"><input type="submit" name="cmd" value="lihat" id="lihat"></div>
<%}%>
</a></td>
```

Its not a good practice creating `button` inside `a` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot... it works like a charm... nice algorithm u have, i can't think like that in the last 5 hours... lol :D